# Bash history not working?

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, command-history

I'm using FreeBSD 11, and Bash as my shell. I've checked all the basics.

- History shows as "on"
- HISTFILE, HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE are all set with sensible values.
- $HISTFILE exists and has rw permissions and a size of 9 bytes (`ls -lt $HISTFILE`)

That should be all that's needed. Yet there we sit. `history` shows nothing. Not a single line is held in the shell, and command history refuses to work.

What else can I try, to get history working?

Comment: After removing `$HISTFILE`, does it get recreated when you open a new bash shell?

Comment: No. I've deleted and tried. Nothing funny in the bashrc file. Also rechecked by setting HISTFILE as a file in /tmp while `su`, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue either. It isn't creating the file and it doesn't seem to be keeping history in shell memory for writing out later, but the file is valid as can be seen because I can manually create it when bash doesn't, using the same variable to be sure its not a typo (`touch $HISTFILE` and `chmod 0666 $HISTFILE`): both work, the file then shows in `ls -lt` and yet _still_ no history, even on starting another session.

Comment: Is histappend set? Can you check the output of `shopt`?